# 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower' tfidf

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization, series

I tried the tfidf to prepare my data but I have the same error.

```
X = df['Description'], df['Type']
y =df['Description'], df['Type']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)


df['Description']=[" ".join(Description) for Description in df['Description'].values]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
t_x_train = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
t_x_test = tfidf.transform(y_test)
```

When I run it this happens
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: What line number/line of code corresponds to that error? Can you give us the full Traceback? Also, can you give us an example of the values in df['Description']

Comment: Here is----> 3 t_x_train = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sklearn tries to apply `str.lower()` on the elements within `y_test`. However, the datatypes seem to be not compatible.

Please check:

1. the datatypes using `y_test.dtypes` or convert to string as shown below
2. whether `y_test` should be replaced with `X_test` when passed to `tfidf`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
corpus = [
 ('This is the first document.',4),
 ('This document is the second document.',3),
 ('And this is the third one.',2),
 ('Is this the first document?',1)
]

df= pd.DataFrame(corpus, columns = ['Description', 'Type'])


X = df['Description']
# make sure your target is also a series of strings if not already
y = df['Type'].astype('str')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
# df['Description']=[" ".join(Description) for Description in df['Description'].values]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
t_x_train = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
t_x_test = tfidf.transform(y_test)
```